# setting model value in jquery progress bar Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to insert a dynamic value for multiple progress bars in a MVC 4 web application. 
I'm looking to set the value based on a number within my model and then have an individual progress bar for each instance of that value.

Currently I am not able to input the model value for progress_no into the javascript and the code for the progressbar only displays for the first instance of the progress number.

The view I am employing looks as below.

```
@model IEnumerable<Piggie.Models.Fund>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Funds Summary";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</hgroup>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GoalAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BalanceAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseOn)
        </th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GoalAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            <p id="progressbar">    

            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseOn)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.progress_no)
    });
  });
  </script>
}
```

I'm not sure of the correct way to implement the value in the java script at bottom but assume if I get this working correctly then an individual progress bar will be created for each instance of the progress_no field.Would this be correct?

EDIT: I think the issue I am really looking to resolve is how to take a variable number stored in a database and use it in javascript in order to create numerous variable progress bars.

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: @*what goes here *@
        });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: What data type is `progress_no`? Can you show the generated JavaScript? Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: id=progressbar in the foreach?

would it not be "better" to set the id="progressBar" + Item.ID?

then you could do something "horrible" and set a hiddenTextbox foreach item and pick that up clientside...

Comment: Progress_no is type int. its a derived number which will never exceed 100. the default figure on the jquery site is 37 so I am looking to create a percentage number which will be the value. There is no error when I compile. when I set the progress value within the script tags to a number I get a progress bar of that value. When I try to change this value to take the progress_no value I get nothing but all still compile.

Comment: When you view the JavaScript that your Razor code is generating does it look correct? Also, your `@Model` is defined as an `IEnumerable`. This means your model won't have a `progress_no` field... Additionally, you won't have a progress bar per field, you'll only have one since you're selecting `#progressbar` by id (there should only be one element with that Id on the page)

Comment: I don't know how to view the javaScript that the Razor code is generating. From your answer above If I want to display multiple various progress bars I'll have to go about it another way. using a partial perhaps?